# AWS route53 failover by using cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, failover, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to achieve fail over with AWS route53 healthcheck by using cloudwatch alarms

I have added following primary and secondary A-records(record-sets)

```
Name = www.example.com (Primary and secondary has same name)
Type = A- Records (Primary and secondary has same name)
TTL = 60Sec (Primary and secondary has same name, recommended by AWS)
Value = IP of primary and secondary servers
Routing policy = Failover
Failover Record Type = Select Primary for Primary/ Select Secondary for secondary
Health Check to Associate = I have only associate health check with Primary A-ecord(recordset)
```

Health check settings

```
IP = Ip address 
Host name = www2 
URL = /abc/
Protocol = HTTP 
String = abc
```

CloudWatch Alarms Settings

```
Whenever = Maximum of Health Check Status 
IS <= 0 
For at Least = 2 
Consecutive period of = 5 minutes
```

By default AWS takes 3 minutes to failover, but i have configured above alarm setting so that it take 10 mints to failover but still it shifted to secondary site before 3 minutes.

Following is aws documentations

[AWS dns-failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html)

[Monitoring Health Checks Using CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-health-checks.html)

Thanks 
Mudasar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put same question on AWS form, following is answer.

```
As far as I know, the alarms can not be used to control Route 53 failover. The health check interval, number of failures required to trigger failover, and all that is currently not configurable. You could probably use a higher TTL for the primary record to delay the failover for some users, though.
```

[DNS failover based on CloudWatch Metrics](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=146437#)